# scrlttr2: Changing the font of all elements at once

Tags: fonts, luatex, koma-script, fontspec, scrlttr2

The [scrlttr2 documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrlttr2) states on page 183

> With the help of the \setkomafont and \addtokomafont commands, you can attach particular
> font styling commands that change the appearance of a given element.

and gives a list of elements.

Is there a way to set the same typeface (loaded with fontspec) for all elements at once?

I.e. get rid of this section, which I would need to update if I add another element to the letter. Also, this section appears to change the font size, which is not intended.

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily{\sansfont}{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{toname}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{toaddress}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{refname}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{refvalue}{\sansfont}
```

```
% !TEX program = lualatex
\documentclass[
    DIN5008B,
    fromphone=true,
    fromemail=true
]{scrlttr2}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\newfontfamily{\sansfont}{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setkomafont{backaddress}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{toname}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{toaddress}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{fromname}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{fromaddress}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{refname}{\sansfont}
\setkomafont{refvalue}{\sansfont}

\begin{document}

\setkomavar{fromname}{Erika Mustermann}
\setkomavar{fromaddress}{Heidestraße 17\\51147 Köln}
\setkomavar{fromphone}[]{+49 123 1234567}
\setkomavar{fromemail}[]{erika.mustermann@example.com}

\setkomavar{date}{\today}

\setkomavar{subject}{Kündigung}

\begin{letter}{
    Deutsche Röhren AG\\
    Goethestraße 7\\
    21614 Buxtehude
}

\opening{Sehr geehrte Damen und Herren,}

Test

\end{letter}
\end{document}
```

Without the aforementioned section:

[image]

With it:

[image]

Comment: What happens if you add `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}` instead of all these commands?

Comment: Or even `\usepackage[default]{heros-otf}` instead of everything after `\usepackage{fontspec}`.

Comment: Thanks, `\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Heros}
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}` does indeed what I want.

Comment: Overleaf doesn't have heros-otf available, but does have TeX Gyre Heros available as a system font. With a local installation, it might be the other way around. So it's good to have both options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possible solutions:

1. Just use `\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}`, because all the KOMA-script fonts in the letter head as a default use sffamily.
2. Even easier: `\usepackage[default]{heros-otf}`, see the package manual, which you get with `texdoc heros`on the command line.